# Task scheduler batch file not executing R script with renv

Tags: r, rstudio, windows-task-scheduler, renv

Created a simple project using Rstudio and included renv.
It simply creates txt file in project directory.

[image]

created batch file:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe" -e "renv::load('C:/Users/username/R/ProjectFolder'); source('C:/Users/username/R/Test1/Test1.R')"> "C:/Users/username/R/Test1/Output.log" 2>&1   
exit
```

If I double click on batch file - works fine.

But if I use task scheduler to run batch file it gives me an error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'renv'
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

Seems like it does not activate renv.

Task scheduler snip:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the task scheduler is not starting R in the project directory. It's the `.Rprofile` file (I believe) that sets up the environment so that `renv` is found. Do you have a way in task-scheduler to set the working directory to that proj dir?

Comment: I dont think I ever set working directory in task scheduler. Snip attached. So is any way i can do it in .Rprofile file?

Comment: this is the only line of code my .Rprofile file has: `source("renv/activate.R")`

Comment: Yes, and that file is not run if the Task Scheduler does not use that project directory as its working directory. https://serverfault.com/q/609651/316496 is relevant, pointing out that it is clearly not automatically what you want it to be. I suggest you start your batch script with something like `CD "C:\Users\username\R\ProjectFolder"` (and then the `CALL ...` on the next line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renv` functionality requires that the R process start in the project directory, calling `Rscript -e /some/path/to/file.R` does not accomplish that. In Task Scheduler, per https://serverfault.com/q/609651/316496, jobs tend to start in `%Windir%\System32\`, not your project directory.

Modify your script so that it *first* changes to the appropriate directory and then calls `Rscript`, perhaps

```batch
CD C:\Users\username\R\ProjectFolder
CALL "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe" -e "renv::load('C:/Users/username/R/ProjectFolder'); source('C:/Users/username/R/Test1/Test1.R')"> "C:/Users/username/R/Test1/Output.log" 2>&1   
exit
```

(I'm not certain if `R\ProjectFolder\` or `R\Test1\` is the project with `.Rprofile` and `renv`'s stuff, adjust as appropriate.